# Does ggplot2 internally change characters and logicals to factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If we plot a factor within `ggplot2`, then it uses the factor levels for the ordering of the data. But if we use vectors of class character and logical, then `ggplot2` orders the plots alphabetically. Interestingly, this is also what happens if we change characters or logicals to factors without specifying any levels - they get ordered alphabetically. I wonder whether `ggplot2` internally converts characters and logicals to factors.

Consider that there are other ways to order data in a vector. For example, the `unique` function returns a vector where first appearance decides which element comes first. Thus `unique(c("b", "a"))` returns `"b" "a"` while `levels(factor(c("b", "a")))` returns `"a" "b"`. The latter corresponds to the ordering if we plot it in `ggplot2`:

```
df <- data.frame(x= c("b", "a", "b"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Does ggplot2 internally change characters and logicals to factors?

Comment: Yeah, it does. — Not sure what `unique` has to do with ordering: it doesn’t change the ordering it all.

Comment: @KonradRudolph As mentioned in the question unique(c("b", "a")) != levels(factor(c("b", "a"))). It shall just show that `ggplot2` seems to use alphabetical ordering as factors but there are other ordering methods, like the one in unique (order by first occurance)